jdk.vm.ci.services.Services ClassNotFoundException when using GraalJsExpressionHandler spring-pug4j
I'm new using spring-pug4j, and I was following the instructions in their page.
I made the Configuration class, as the following:
package com.xxxx.xxx.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;

import de.neuland.pug4j.PugConfiguration;
import de.neuland.pug4j.spring.template.SpringTemplateLoader;
import de.neuland.pug4j.spring.view.PugViewResolver;

@Configuration
public class PugConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateLoader templateLoader() {
        SpringTemplateLoader templateLoader = new SpringTemplateLoader();
        templateLoader.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/templates");
        templateLoader.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateLoader.setSuffix(".pug");
        return templateLoader;
    }

    @Bean
    public PugConfiguration pugConfiguration() {
        PugConfiguration configuration = new PugConfiguration();
        configuration.setCaching(false);
        configuration.setTemplateLoader(templateLoader());
        configuration.setExpressionHandler(new GraalJsExpressionHandler());
        return configuration;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        PugViewResolver viewResolver = new PugViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setConfiguration(pugConfiguration());
        return viewResolver;
    }
}

But when I tried to compile It, I got a large maven error telling me:
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.vm.ci.services.Services
...

The dependency I'm using is:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.neuland-bfi</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-pug4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

I have to say that works fine this way ( commenting «configuration.setExpressionHandler(new GraalJsExpressionHandler())» ):
@Configuration
public class PugConfig {
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateLoader templateLoader() {
        SpringTemplateLoader templateLoader = new SpringTemplateLoader();
        templateLoader.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/templates");
        templateLoader.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateLoader.setSuffix(".pug");
        return templateLoader;
    }

    @Bean
    public PugConfiguration pugConfiguration() {
        PugConfiguration configuration = new PugConfiguration();
        configuration.setCaching(false);
        configuration.setTemplateLoader(templateLoader());
        //configuration.setExpressionHandler(new GraalJsExpressionHandler());
        return configuration;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        PugViewResolver viewResolver = new PugViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setConfiguration(pugConfiguration());
        return viewResolver;
    }
}

Why this happens?
Does it have any solution?
Thanks, in advance.
